# How can a Twilio user reply to take a specific action

Tags: sms, twilio

So here's our desired sequence of events:

1. We use Twilio to text our users with a notification about a specific transaction on our web app, which includes a simple call to action, e.g. 'Hi Alice. Your transaction regarding your teddy bear is pending. Please reply with "YES" to approve this transaction'.
2. The user replies "YES"
3. This triggers a call to an endpoint on our server which changes the status of this transaction to 'approved' in our database.

The problem is that we can't figure out **how to keep track of WHICH transaction** a particular SMS is linked to.

**Our ideas so far:**

- give the user a code e.g. 'Please reply with "APPROVE EH384F" to
  approve this transaction', but this obviously detracts from user
  experience and we would rather it be really simple.
- Set a [twilio cookie.](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136287-How-do-Twilio-cookies-work-). but these seem to expire after
  4 hours, and we don't want the text to only work if the user replies
  within 4 hours.

Can anyone give us any pointers on how we could go about this?

Comment: Could you check if there is more than one transaction pending, if so, approve that one, otherwise, ask the user for which one?

Comment: I think again that would just be too much effort for most users, especially if there were lots of transactions. We really want it to just be "Reply YES to approve" and have that response somehow be tied to the transaction that triggered the notification

Comment: Do you know the odds of people having more than one transaction? How about lots of transactions? This should be put into the equation. It's easy to fall into the trap of fighting the worst case scenario. Also, the problem with SMS is that it's hard to track if messages are rightfully sent/received (at least in Canada). So that "YES" reply from them could be to a prior message of yours, if there are more than one transaction.

Comment: Odds are not insignificant of there being multiple transactions. Yes that's the problem. We can't base our action simply off the number we receive the SMS from as this will not be uniquely linked to a transaction. We need to somehow track the SMS, and I was wondering if there is a way to do this through Twilio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a group (pool) of Twilio numbers to send the messages.

Once a message is sent using a number, get that number out of the group, keep it associated with the user (and the phone number of the user) from where you expect the response (don't use it to send another SMS until you get the response from the user).

When you get the response also check from where it comes, if all OK put the number back in the group.

If the user does not respond in due time, free your Twilio number an put it back in the group.